# PMD-Jenkins: how to use it

Tags: jenkins

I don't know how to use the PMD-jenkins plugin to generate and show my result.

How to generate and show the PMD result in Jenkins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PMD jenkins plugin is only displaying the PMD check results. You need to run PMD using Maven as part of your build triggered by Jenkins. For example this could look like that in your `pom.xml`

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Then PMD-jenkins will know where to pick up the results and publish them for you.

To get the results you will need to add this code to your `pom.xml` and execute the according target in Jenkins, yes.

Note that this is not related to PMD-plugin in Eclipse. The Eclipse PMD plugin just shows the result of the local analysis, not related to Jenkins.

Comment: You mean I need to add this part into my pom.xml and then excute my maven project in Jenkins?

Comment: however I have integrated pmd plug-in and maven plugin in my eclipse. And i have analysed my maven project by pmd in eclipse. so how to show the result just in jenkins? the same?

Comment: Thanks, and I have done that as ur instructions. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308829/jenkins-how-to-use-the-pmd-plugin-to-analyze-a-maven-project?noredirect=1#comment25102852_17308829

Comment: I have written this bug in another topic of stack overflow.could you please help me check it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this command-

```
clean install org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.6:pmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps:
1. install pmd plugin.

```
Manage jenkins-> manage plugin -> click on available plugin -> search "pmd plugin" -> install
```

2. goto job and in build section write

```
mvn clean install pmd:pmd
```

3. In post build section choose

```
"Publish PMD analysis results"
```