# How to integrate PMD, Maven and Hudson?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, static-analysis, pmd

I tries one scenario to integrate these tools, but it giving unbelievable output. What I did:

1. I did not configure or install PMD in Hudson.
2. I configured PMD in my parent pom.
3. I run goals (clean site) the in Hudson job, but it running only last sub project.

   I check log in console, it has:

   ```
   some svn update log 
   Parsing POMs
   and directly generating reports for last sub project.
   ```
4. I have same svn checkout workspace in Eclipse, it working and generating reports for all parent and child projects. Actually, after verify in Eclipse only, I try to verify in Hudson.

And after try to configure PMD in Hudson, but I did not find any help online to do that.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and [maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) and [sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) (which contains PMD, Checkstyle, Findbugs and others).
I didn't set it up however there are plugins for (nearly) everything:

- [Jenkins Artifactory Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin)
- [Jenkins Maven Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin)
- [Jenkins Sonar Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sonar+plugin)

But it is possible to do it your way and use PMD "directly". Hava a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294515/pmd-jenkins-how-to-use-it)...